# How to get Kc key and TMSI number with AT command in Linux

Tags: kali-linux, usb, modem, smartphone

I've completely configured the port with opened modem on `ttyACM0` as my mobile device `(HTC M8)`. However, it didn't allow me to enter anything.

I've tried with hotkey `Ctrl-A Z`, but there was no news. I don't know how to send an `AT command` to get more information.

If you've done so far, please help me get through this step or it's nice to have any idea.

[image: Image1]

Answer (score 1):

Typing `<ret>ATZ<ret>` should produce an OK prompt. Similarly for ATE1, ATI0, or AT&V

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hayes_command_set

Comment: I've tried to type with three characters as `A` `T` `Z` like an invisible characters because they were not display in my screen and nothing then happened. I cannot enter anything even `OK`.

Comment: It sounds like your ttyACM0 device is not connected to the desired modem, or not connected to a modem that is listening for commands, or perhaps speed/parity/flow-control don't match the device. In desperation you might try `+++` before the Z reset command above, but it sounds as though that's unlikely to work, either. Debug info from dmesg, lsusb, or the like might shed some light on it.

Comment: You're right. The `+++` doesn't work as I've tried. Thanks for your sharing. Please get back if you have any news or sharing.